# Setting HTML/CSS background color

Tags: javascript, css, linux, html

So, I'm a beginner with HTML5 and CSS and I've downloaded a template that I'm using from http://html5up.net/. Inside the zip, there's different folders such as css, images, js, index.html. How do I change the background color of a particular section? Would I change it inside the css or change I change it inside the index.html file?

Is there a way to compile changes to the css file on a linux machine without even 'less'? I'm on a school computer at UT and I'm not allowed to install 'less' on the machines.

Comment: google "css tutorial" ...

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any additional plugin for that, simply link up a stylesheet and declare a rule to style the element:

In your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_stylesheet.css">
```

In your HTML:

```
<div class="foo">I am a test div</div>
```

In your CSS:

```
.foo { background-color: #000000; }
```

Or you can provide an inline style:

```
<div style="background-color:#000000;">I am a test div</div>
```